# Collecting title from youtube using api give strange behavior in jekyll

Tags: javascript, jekyll, youtube-data-api

I used following code to get youtube title in my jekyll blog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getyoutubetitle(videoID) {
        $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+videoID+'&key=AIzaSyDfqskjJZVzNMKVs1c7dXvlDC2rpjrB60&part=snippet&callback=?',function(data){
            if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
                document.write(data.items[0].snippet.title);
            } else {
                console.log('video not exists');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

When using `<script>getyoutubetitle("iClTTtecJhs");</script>` I get page reloaded to give only the title of video and all other content of blog gone.

http://songs.justinechacko.in/malayalam/2018/02/01/file5.html

Comment: I also tried opening the website and it was taking a long time to load. You seem to be loading a lot of videos and pictures. Maybe consider using pagination and having a limit of 10 or so videos per page. That would significantly lower page load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is that you're just writing to the page. You need to rewrite the specific HTML node of wherever you want to display the title.

For example, if you want to change the text of a header with the id `videoTitle01`, then you would do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getyoutubetitle(nodeID, videoID) {
        let node = '#' + nodeID;
        let apiKey = 'AIzaSyDfqskjJZVzNMKVs1c7dXvlDC2rpjrB60';
        let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + videoID + '&part=snippet&key=' + apiKey;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            if (data && data.items && data.items[0]) {
                $(node).text(data.items[0].snippet.title);
            } else {
                console.log('video not exists');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

...

<script>
    getyoutubetitle('videoTitle01','iClTTtecJhs');
</script>
<h1 id="videoTitle01"><h1>
```

Comment: Your old code didn't check if `data.items` is undefined. If you try to get `data.items[0]` when `data.items` is undefined, it throws the `Cannot read` error. I updated my answer to have a better conditional in the if statement.

Comment: Still not getting the title

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hs5ot8mr/

Here's a JSFiddle where I set up the code you're running. Whenever I use my api key, it works. Whenever I use your key, it fails to get the title. I looked at the response message from the API, and it says `usageLimits` and `keyInvalid`.

So, I think the issue is that your API key has been used too much and is no longer valid/recognized by the API. You need to renew your key, make a new one, or wait until you get more quota.

Comment: Thanks for support. Actually this is the key `AIzaSyDfqskjJZXVzNMKVs1c7dXvlDC2rpjrB60`. You places it incorrectly. I get title in jsfiddle, but not in my website

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pvwnoxut/ You're changing the same header twice. You need to have a separate place to put each title. Every video needs a different header with a unique ID.

Comment: Thanks, but still [here](http://songs.justinechacko.in/malayalam/2018/02/01/file5.html) it doesn't work.

Comment: may be que to limit exceeds

Comment: I looked at the HTML for that page. The code is rendering `<p>` tags and `<script>` tags correctly. But, the `<h1>` tags are not being rendered correctly. They are rendering like text and not like HTML. It looks like they are rendering as `&lt;h1&gt;`. This outputs text, not HTML. You need to use `<` and `>`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity If you want to output `<` as text, use `&lt;`. If you want to output `<` as code, use `<`. You want to output as code. Use `<` instead of `&lt;` and it will solve your bugs. Look here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Comment: Yes, you can use any header 1-6: `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`. It just depends on how big you want your header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Comment: Do I need a corresponding change in the javascript code?

Comment: No, the JavaScript does not need to change.